# Nodejs TCP server process packets in order

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

I am using a tcp server to recieve and process packets in Node.js. It should recieve 2 packets:

- "create" for creating an object in a database. It first checks if the object already exists and then creates it. (-> takes some time process)
- "update" for updating the newly created object in the database

For the sake of simplicity, we'll just assume the first step *always* takes longer than the second. (which is always true in my original code)

This is a MWE:

```
const net = require("net");

const server = net.createServer((conn) => {
  conn.on('data', async (data) => {
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} recieved`);
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} done`);
  });
});
server.listen(1234);
const client = net.createConnection(1234, 'localhost', async () => {
  client.write("create");
  await sleep(10); // just a cheap workaround to "force" sending 2 packets instead of one
  client.write("update");
});

// Just to make it easier to read
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

If i run this code i get:

```
Instruction create recieved
Instruction update recieved
Instruction create done
Instruction update done
```

But i want the "create" instruction to block the `conn.on('data', func)` until the last callback returns asynchronously. The current code tries to update an entry before it is created in the database which is not ideal.

Is there an (elegant) way to achieve this? I suspect some kind of buffer which stores the data and a worker loop of some kind which processes the data? But how do i avoid running an infinite loop which blocks the event loop? (Event loop is the correct term, is it?)

Note: I have a lot more logic to handle fragmentation, etc. But this explains the issue i'm having.

Comment: `... just a cheap workaround to "force" sending 2 packets instead of one ...` TCP is a stream protocol. There are no *packets*. But there is *order*.

Comment: @wildplasser There are no packets in TCP, correct. But there are in IP, which i was referring to. I want the *single* TCP *stream* to be sent in *two* IP *packets*.

Comment: You might be able to confuse Nagle, but you cannot confuse the TCP window negotiation. Your *solution* is fundamentally wrong. The real solution is: design a protocol. (the simplest possible protocol: add a '\n' after each *packet*. And yes: the receiver will have to buffer the incoming data)`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with the package [async-fifo-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-fifo-queue).
It's not the cleanest solution but it should do what i want and as efficient as possible (using async/await instead of just looping infinitely).

Code:

```
const net = require("net");
const afq = require("async-fifo-queue");

const q = new afq.Queue();

const server = net.createServer((conn) => {
  conn.on('data', q.put.bind(q));
});
server.listen(1234);
const client = net.createConnection(1234, 'localhost', async () => {
  client.write("create");
  await sleep(10);
  client.write("update");
});

(async () => {
  while(server.listening) {
    const data = await q.get();
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} recieved`);
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} done`);
  }
})();



function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the socket when you get the "create" event. After it finishes, you can resume the socket. Example:

```js
const server = net.createServer((conn) => {
  conn.on('data', async (data) => {
    if (data === 'create') {
        conn.pause()
    }
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} recieved`);
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(`Instruction ${data} done`);
    if (data === 'create') {
        conn.resume()
    }
  });
});
server.listen(1234);
const client = net.createConnection(1234, 'localhost', async () => {
  client.write("create");
  await sleep(10); // just a cheap workaround to "force" sending 2 packets instead of one
  client.write("update");
});

// Just to make it easier to read
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing pause() and resume() functions, but it still adds data to the queue when it's paused. If someone thinks a job is going to take some time, using pause() and resume() can be a simple solution (like a simple session lock).

// Pause and resume, packets not lost

```
socket.pause();
setTimeout(() => {
    socket.resume();
    console.log("Data still received");
}, 8000);
```